# How do I make a screen array of 10000 divs with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, coordinate-systems

I'm a beginner at jQuery and want to make a self-running screen display just for fun.

Inside .container, I would need a relative positioned div class .Canvas (not HTML5) 1000px by 1000px replete with 10px by 10px absolute positioned divs. so the whole thing is a rectilinear grid of 10x10 squares.
I know it needs to have 100 y coords and 100 x coords.

I know I could make a 'for' function to iterate 10000 times through 
    document.write(''); 
as h goes from  = 0 to < 100, then v=v++ , h=0 again, etc, till and including h==99 && v==99, then copying and pasting all this written html output onto a document as a sloppy mass of code. 
Then repeating the same process to generate a CSS file of all classes .V0 to .V99 and all classes .H0 to .H99 . All V classes would lend top position and all H classes would lend left position (at increments of ten pixels). All dimensions could be designated by 
    .Canvas div{position:absolute;width:10px;height:10px;}

I'd like to know how to generate all these little buggers on the fly with jQuery.

I'd also like to give all the divs the same 1000px by 1000px background img, but each offset by increments of 10px, so that if all the divisions are opaque, the viewer sees the entire img as a seamless entity, then as each randomly selected 10x10 div, with timed delay, drops to opacity=0, more and more 'holes' appear in it until it disintegrates completely and an entirely different img is revealed residing on a z-index below.

What would be the elegant way to designate a background position to each of these little suckers? 
Is there some shortcut way to write the CSS by using 'child' , enumerating child number, or?

I know this is a lot of stuff, but perhaps someone might find it interesting to give me some hints.. ??

Many thanks!

Mike in Los Angeles. An old fart to be just learning such newfangled tricks at 63.

Comment: Show us that you tried something we are not free labor. We help we do not do the work.

Comment: What part of your question are you having the most difficulty with, generating the grid itself?

Comment: You know, I really thought about that a lot, Iznogood. I knew someone was likely to pull that one out of their hat. I don't need to be taught a child's lesson by you. If you really looked at, you'll see that I put a lot of thought into what I wrote and cursively explained how I knew to proceed with doing as much as I know how.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a sprite to work with, but I did it with random hex values. If you want to have a look, dissect & digest, and then get back to me with questions I'd be glad to help.

> http://jsfiddle.net/8HyYt/

**EDIT 1**

I made the canvas 10000 as you wanted, but it overloads the memory of firefox, and would likely destroy most computers anyway. But this is an example flaw on my part, not on your end. I also understand that my question wasn't forward enough regarding the complexity of the situation. Using the sprite I would apply it normally, such as:

```
#canvas div{
  background-image:url('path/to/my/sprite.png');
}
```

Then, for each of the divs that are found, we can randomize the position that we refer too in our iterator.

```
var tenbyten = $(".tenbyten");
$.each(tenbyten, function(index,value){
  //accepting negative and positive values, working with a range of 1000, or -1000
  //and incrementing on values of 10, we have two randoms
  //one for the top position and one for the left position.
  var randomTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)*10 - 500;
  var randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)*10 - 500;
  //for every element with a class of tenbyten found
  //we give it a random background within our sprite.
  $(this).css({"background-position" : randomTop+"px "+randomLeft+"px" });
});
```

**EDIT 2**

For the above example, I used '1000px' and not '10000px'. If you need 10000px, then you need to change the math as such:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)*10 - 5000;
```

This will give you the proper value.

Comment: Wow, that's something for me to digest! I appreciate it. And will get back to you. That's generosity!

Comment: I took it a step further for you.

Comment: The fiddle will simplify considerably - try this version - http://jsfiddle.net/2fqj3/

Comment: I like it. glad I can gain some clarity and perspective. Appreciate it beetroot.

Comment: Beetroot, that's genius... but, um, I don't understand it. You wrote two variables as arrays..  var r=[], c=[]; First of all, I thought all variables had to be separated by a ";" or be on a new line.. I understand you named them r for row and c for column.. but how do the two arrays "know" how to fill up? Is this a special javascript shortcut for writing a two dimensional array? Can you perhaps point me to a learning source about this? I also don't know this hex way of generating rgb values so easily.. I would have made 3 separate number generators! Geniuses, you guys!

Comment: He does not use var r=[] or c=[]. You can declare variables in a comma-separated-values format. SO...var blue=1, red=2, green=3, orange=4; until the ';' ends the var statement, each comma separates a new variable declaration. You can remove r=[] and c=[] from the function and it will work properly. I'd only separated as I did to clear the floats. You'll notice that if you run this in IE7/IE8, it will not work.